# igraph initialisation with weights

Tags: python, igraph, vertices, edges

How can I initialise an igraph with weights?

This is what I have

```
cr = csv.reader(open("atlas.csv","rb"))

mapping = {}
for row in cr:
    if int(row[2]) == 1:
        continue

    source = int(row[0])
    target = int(row[1])

    if source in mapping:
        list = mapping[source]
        list.append(target)
    else:
        mapping[source] = [target]

print mapping

G = Graph(edges = [(v, a) for v in mapping.keys() for a in mapping[v]])
print G
```

I tried adding weight using `edges = (v, a, w)` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, you may use [`TupleList`](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#TupleList) method:

> If you have a weighted graph, you can
>   use items where the third item contains the weight of the edge by
>   setting `edge_attrs` to `"weight"` or `["weight"]`.

You may also set `weights` parameter to `True`:

> `weights` - alternative way to specify that the graph is weighted. If
>   you set weights to true and `edge_attrs` is not given, it will be
>   assumed that `edge_attrs` is `["weight"]` and `igraph` will parse the third
>   element from each item into an edge weight. If you set `weights` to a
>   string, it will be assumed that `edge_attrs` contains that string only,
>   and `igraph` will store the edge weights in that attribute.

Comment: I have made a solution hope thats what you meant. Thanks.